# Nuxt.js routes limit possible parameter options

Tags: vue.js, vue-router, nuxt.js

I have the following url structure in my Nuxt.js app.

`/pages/_wildcard/_id.vue`

which basically corresponds to `example.com/*/*`

I am looking for a way to only fire that page when visiting specific parameters.

For example, I would like to only allow only `clothes`, `electronics` and `babies` as the possible wildcard value which correspond to

- example.com/clothes/*
- example.com/electronics/*
- example.com/babies/*

Anything else other than the three of them shouldn't go to this page.

The problem occurs since the first parameter is a wildcard. I am looking for a way to only allow specific wildcard values in the route. Is there anything like that?

The only thing I thought is having an if statement inside the asyncData method to do the validation but I'd like to avoid that. Looking for a better solution here.

Comment: Is there any solution for this ? I want to do the same for a particular route in nuxt pages.

Answer (score 0):

Vue-router has fantastic way of [dynamic redirects](https://router.vuejs.org/guide/essentials/redirect-and-alias.html#redirect) / checks:

```
const router = new VueRouter({
  routes: [
    { path: '/a', redirect: to => {
      // the function receives the target route as the argument
      // return redirect path/location here.
    }}
  ]
})
```

You can place route checks into this function and perform any needed validations.

Or... you can use the full power of [Vue-router reg-exp](https://github.com/pillarjs/path-to-regexp#custom-matching-parameters) and write your path in router.js like this one:

```
/(clothes|electronics|babies)/*
```

Comment: Thanks for answer. Any chance you know how to do that in nuxt.js since we do not have direct access to the VueRouter creation?

Comment: @mauxtin, how and where do you define your URL paths? Isn't this what you need https://nuxtjs.org/api/configuration-router#extendroutes ?

Comment: @mauxtin, here is the solution for your case: https://nuxtjs.org/api/configuration-generate#routes . You just need to set an array of predefined url parts in your nuxt.config.js.

Comment: This doesn't seem to be the way to be solved since generate is only used with static page generation which isn't the case.

Comment: @mauxtin, maybe you are right. Saw that in docs while was reading about nuxj :)